# Palm detection doesn't work in Ubuntu 18.04 (X1E)

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, touchpad, synaptics

I am running Kubuntu 18.04 with latest synaptics driver on my ThinkPad X1 Extreme and my palm detection doesn't work. I suspect it's because the synaptics driver is not getting value `ABS_TOOL_WIDTH` from `/dev/input/event*` which is a known problem but I don't know how to fix that. I need to force the driver to determine palm by pressure, not by width of the touch.

One possible solution would be to patch the driver. I could do the programming but I don't know how to build it and give it to system...

This is output of my synclient

```
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 1574
    RightEdge               = 5368
    TopEdge                 = 1409
    BottomEdge              = 4447
    FingerLow               = 25
    FingerHigh              = 30
    MaxTapTime              = 180                                                                                                                                           
    MaxTapMove              = 246
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = -113
    HorizScrollDelta        = 113
    VertEdgeScroll          = 1
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
    MinSpeed                = 2.90133
    MaxSpeed                = 10.6228
    AccelFactor             = 0
    TouchpadOff             = 1
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 3
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.100007
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 1
    PalmMinWidth            = 0
    PalmMinZ                = 63
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 0
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 20
    VertHysteresis          = 20
    ClickPad                = 1
    RightButtonAreaLeft     = 3471
    RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
    RightButtonAreaTop      = 4058
    RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

Comment: I suggest using `libinput` instead of synaptics. It can work without WIDTH.